# smartgit ubuntu 13.04 64bits crash startup

Tags: java, startup

I try to launch smartgit with ubuntu 13.04 but it crash on startup.

I tried with openjdk and the oracle java.

Here is the error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffe85fe5009, pid=10572, tid=140732854384384
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6e009]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x19
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/pol/Programmes/smartgithg-4_5_2/bin/hs_err_pid10572.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
./smartgithg.sh : ligne 74 : 10572 Abandon                 (core dumped)$_JAVA_EXEC $_VM_PROPERTIES -Xmx${SMARTGITHG_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -Xverify:none -Dsmartgit.vm-xmx=${SMARTGITHG_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -jar "$SMARTGIT_HOME/lib/bootloader.jar" "$@"
```

I don't know what to do to make it work..

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64bits with java version "1.7.0_21".

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Eclipse and I found this:

> For a workaround add the following to the end of your eclipse.ini
>   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501/comments/35

Maybe you can try something similar on smartgit...